# Как выбрать из большого лог-файла?

Tags: логирование, big-data

друзья.

Есть компания, которая продаёт просмотры баннеров в Интернете.

За всё время в логе накопилось 300 млн. записей. Лог состоит из следующих записей:

- id пользователя (хеш-код)
- дата просмотра

В последнее время за сутки в лог-файл добавляется 10 млн. записей. Каждый пользователь за всё время делает от 10 до 100 просмотров, если смотреть по медиане.

Требуется сделать систему, которая за время меньше 1 сек. выдаёт количество уникальных пользователей, которые просматривали баннеры.

Максимальный промежуток дат — 3 года, минимальный — 1 день, сегодняшнюю дату запрашивать нельзя. На компьютере бесконечный HD, 2 ядра процессора, 4 Гб ОЗУ.

**С помощью каких технологий можно это реализовать?**

Comment: С таким железом, скоростью добавления данных и вашим условием < 1 секунды... Нет таких технологий.

Comment: Есть информация по среднему и максимальному времени жизни одного пользователя ? Т.е. время от его самого первого до последнего запроса

Comment: Ну-у-у-у, если задача просто показывать кол-во уникальных юзеров (хешей), то наверно можно схитрить. Если учесть, что кол-во надо показывать за промежуток времени и при этом нельзя показывать "за сегодня", то наверно самый банальный вариант - доработать систему логгирования таким образом, чтоб она либо считала каждый день кол-во уникальных хешей, либо написать для этого скрипт. Результат можно в любую реляционную БД скаладывать в таблицу в виде `date | count`. Полагаю, select из такой таблицы будет выполняться недолго, пусть даже за 3 года. Но это только в теории конечно :)

Comment: @nobody Если сегодня 100тыс уникальных (в пределах дня) и вчера 100тыс уникальных, то за 2 дня у нас не 200к уникальных, а явно меньше, потому что часть пользователей которые были сегодня были еще и вчера и значит надо заново их пересчитывать, складывать 100+100 не выйдет

Comment: Какая жаль, а так хотелось :(

Comment: @nobody На самом деле не было бы особой проблемой хранить в таблице посчитанные количества за все возможные промежутки времени за 3 года. БД с индексом поднимет нужную запись моментально. Но вот первичный расчет это гораздо интереснее

Comment: Да расчитывать-то можно каждый день хоть даже в течении дня скриптом. Мне почему-то кажется, что с учётом индекса БД в памяти займёт больше чем 4G ...

Comment: @nobody Обычными средствами БД посчитать уникальных группами по интервалам дней среди 300млн записей не реально. Поэтому я и спросил у ТС время жизни пользователя, что бы представлять необходимую глубину анализа

Comment: @Mike, нет такой информации..

Comment: @nobody.. да но мы в этом случае будем знать сколько каждый день уникальных пользователей. За период будет меньшее число.

Comment: @СергейПротасов Готовых систем вы таких в любом случае не найдете, особенно на такие ресурсы. значит только очень хитрые собственные алгоритмы. А для разработки такого алгоритма статистическая информация по имеющимся данным, вроде вот этого времени жизни пользователя очень важна. Я бы в любом случае если бы передо мной стояла такая задача сначала сделал бы скрипты которые бы дали мне нужную статистику

Comment: Хотя можете посмотреть в сторону систем работы с логами типа kibana

Comment: ТС, по сути у вас работа с аггрегированными данными. Такие данные, чтобы выдавать за < 1 сек, можно либо готовить заранее, и хранить в любой БД, либо использовать специализированные столбцовые базы данных. Посмотрите в сторону [Clickhouse](https://tech.yandex.ru/clickhouse/). PS. Лог-файл... придется переделать на СУБД и мигрировать прошлые данные

Comment: В общем из велосипедов на вскидку есть идея хранить по каждому пользователю битовую маску в какие дни он был. на 3 года это около 100 байт на пользователя. тогда задача подсчета уникальных на интервале дат сведется к подсчету пользователей с хотя бы одним единичным битом в определенной области карты. встанет вопрос эффективного сравнения пользователей при добавлении, думаю можно пойти по пути прямого перевода идентификатора пользователя в адрес его структуры. фактически хеш таблица с некоторой областью переполнения. ее параметры надо будет подобрать опытным путем

Comment: И да, нет гарантии, что уложимся в секунду на поиск, особенно если нужная часть карты не будет умещаться в ОЗУ. тогда надо будет раз в сутки после обновления карты просчитывать и хранить агрегированные данные

Comment: Пилить файлы на бесконечном HDD, и делать ежедневные/еженедельные/ежемесячные промежуточные выборки, а вот калькуляцию по ним сливать в бд, соответственно за день, неделю, месяц. На выборках из бд суммировать. А вообще такая задача с бигдатой требует соответствующих серверов и технологий. Реализация их (технологий) не есть типовая задача, и на сегодняшний день является ноу-хау в каждом конкретном случае.

Comment: @Mike _В общем из велосипедов на вскидку есть идея хранить по каждому пользователю битовую маску в какие дни он был._

А может наоборот с строке даты держать битовую маску пользователей?

Comment: может быть. пробовать надо. смотреть что быстрее.